# html, one column auto increment numbering

Tags: html

```
   <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Num</td>
          <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
       <? foreach {{ ?>
        <tr>
           <td>here this must be html auto increment number</td>
           <td>this will be from database</td>
        <tr>
       <? endforeach; ?>
   </table>
```

The `<td>Num</td>` should auto-increment the number on the page.
Is it possible to do this in HTML without any JavaScript, or another simple solution?

Comment: Take a look at `counter-increment`(CSS). http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp

Comment: What serverlanguage are you using? PHP? You could change your foreach to a for loop like: for ($i = 0; $i < COUNT; $i++){echo $i; echo $dbObject[$i].Name;}. Or you could create a variable that increments like: $i = 0; foreach (){echo $i++;}.

Comment: it's ok the for each is not meant here

Comment: @bzeaman Thanks so much man! you are a savior! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try using `counter-increment`:

```css
table {
    counter-reset: tableCount;     
}
.counterCell:before {              
    content: counter(tableCount); 
    counter-increment: tableCount; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Num</td>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="counterCell"></td>
    <td>this will be from database</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="counterCell"></td>
    <td>this will be from database</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Support for which seems pretty good: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters